# Static Bayesian networks using p-values

Tags: bayesian, p-value, continuous-data, bayesian-network

In your opinion, what is the best way of handling Bayesian networks using continuous data, in this particular case, p-values?

I have read about several discretization techniques, Gaussian approaches, etc., but I'm quite lost due the controversies each approach has.

Also, while I found a lot of literature regarding how to handle temporal series for both static and dynamic Bayesian networks, I didn't find a good reference for handling p-values.